# Spring mvc and Hibernate validator, error

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-mvc, validation

I'm using Spring 3 with hibernate for the validation of a controller.

When my form is correct it will redirect me to the page that I want, but when the validation has a problem, it just breaks and send me to a "not found" page. I think my structure is correct, so I dont get it.

```
@RequestMapping(params = "guardaNuevo", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String guardaSimCard(  @ModelAttribute("validator")@Valid CatalogoSimCardValidator validator, HttpServletRequest request,Model model,BindingResult result) {
    System.out.println("--------------------------------");

    model.addAttribute("CatalogoSimCardValidator", new CatalogoSimCardValidator());
    System.out.println(result);
    System.out.println("no errores");
}
```

My validator looks like this:

```
public class CatalogoSimCardValidator   {

    @NotNull 
    private int idSimCard;
    @NotEmpty (message="La descripción no puede venir vacía")
    private String descripcionSimCard="";
    @NotNull
    @NumberFormat(style=Style.CURRENCY)
    private double precio;

    @NumberFormat(style=Style.NUMBER)
    private int version=0;
    @NotEmpty
    private String descripcionVers;
```

and obviously I'm not missing:

```
<context:component-scan base-package="com.telcel.sds.crm.dlyscrm.precios.web"/>
<context:annotation-config/>
<mvc:annotation-driven  />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your method signature to put the `BindingResult` parameter next to the at `@Valid` parameter

```
public String guardaSimCard(@ModelAttribute("validator") @Valid CatalogoSimCardValidator validator, BindingResult result, HttpServletRequest request, Model model) {
```

I assume the Exception you get is an `IllegalStateException` (it would help if you posted it) coming from an `ErrorsMethodArgumentResolver` and states

> An Errors/BindingResult argument is expected to be declared
>   immediately after the model attribute, the @RequestBody or the
>   @RequestPart arguments to which they apply: [...]

Comment: wOW THANK YOU MAN!!! IT WAS THE BINDING RESULT ORDER, YOU SAVE MY LIFE!! THANKS THANKS THANKS!